# the jpg file isn't show on spring boot web

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web

Hi i am making web to show the my profile so i want to insert my pictures in html file but when i tried it it didn't work.. so what is the problems?!

This is my controller code

```
package com.tutorial.springboot.Controller;


import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;


@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class controller {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String hi() {
        return "efef";
    }
}
```

This is my Apllication code

```
package com.tutorial.springboot;


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is my Application.properties code

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html

spring.application.name=Bootstrap Spring Boot
```

This is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        p{text-align: center}

    </style>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>iefsdfnef</h1>
<img src="123.jpg" width="1000" th:src="@{/123.jpg}"/>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my pox.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.tutorial</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

So if someone knows that why it can't show the jpg files please teach me also if you know the solutions tell me

Thank you!

Comment: Debug this using your browser tools: Inspect the `img src` in the HTML that the browser gets, then see what the Network tab tells you about the request to load the image.

Comment: when i check <img src="/123.jpg"> find this

Comment: i think this is collect